How to pretty-print json in Serilo expression?
I am using following Serilog expression:
loggerConfiguration = loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
     "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3} {Service,-8}] {@m}{#if _logRest is not null}\n{ {..rest()} }{#end}\n{@x}", theme: TemplateTheme.Code));

\n{ {..rest()} } outputs rest of properties as JSON like this:
[10:13:35 INF MY_SERVICE] Processed message
{"A":"B","C":"D","E":{"F":"G"}}

Is there a way to pretty-print JSON? I want log line to look like this (pretty-printed with removed double quotes if possible):
[10:13:35 INF MY_SERVICE] Processed message
{
    A: B,
    C: D,
    E:
    {
        F: G
    }
}

